# Webpack + angular 1.x + gulp + minifying

Tags: angularjs, webpack, gulp, minify, uglifyjs

I'm having trouble setting up Webpack to properly minify my app. I am creating to separate JS files, one vendor.js (libraries) and main.js (my application). I have looked and scouted around about my issue and can't seem to find a proper solution.


webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var ngAnnotatePlugin = require('ng-annotate-webpack-plugin');

let vendors = [
  'angular',
  'lodash',
  'moment',
  'angular-ui-router',
  'angular-loading-bar',
  'angular-filter',
  'angular-animate'
];

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './halo/app.js',
    vendor: vendors
  },
  output: {
    filename: './build/main.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: "vendor",
      filename:"./build/vendor.js"
    }),
    new ngAnnotatePlugin({
      add: true
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

My issue is, without minification, the app works fine. When i minify the application and vendor, it doesnt seem to work. I get unknown provider errors.

I have read about mangling, but that doesn't seem to fix my problem either (unless I'm not doing it properly). I also am doing ngInject in all the right places.

I found this config snippit to put inside optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({})

```
{
  beautify: false, // Don't beautify output
  comments: false, // Eliminate comments
  // Compression specific options
  compress: {
    warnings: false,
    drop_console: true
  },
  mangle: {
    except: ['$'], // Don't mangle $
    screw_ie8 : true, // Don't care about IE8
    keep_fnames: true // Don't mangle function names
  }
}
```

can anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: What providers are failing? What do your controllers look like?

Comment: after debugging for a while, the controllers are fine, ng-annotate is injecting dependencies properly, but i get an error that provider 'a' is not available. not much help but I'm still in the process of figuring it out

Comment: the issue seems to be with the mangle option.

Comment: Have you tried removing the mangle option? I use `mangle: { except:['angular'] }` and this works with webpack, uglify, angualr1 in my project. I also don't use ng-annotate and do that manually in controllers, directives, etc. I know I had some issues with it (ng-annotate)!

Comment: I just tried and unfortunately, it still doesnt work. But what seems to work is i just turn mangle off completely. I guess I will go with that solution for now

Answer (score 0):

Cant put it as comments, as I have less reputations.

What you can do is, use `strict-di` rather than `ng-annotate`. Solve all the issues reported by `strict-di` and then use minification with mangling on.

[strict-di](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi) forces you to define all your dependencies in array format within code. [read this answer about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33494022/what-is-the-benefit-of-angularjs-strict-di-mode)

Comment: the problem is not the injection of dependencies. Webpack is injecting the dependencies properly. I see it whenever it builds the output js file

Comment: then the other issue mostly would be to do with `window.angular` would be undefined, check if by running application and then dev-tools console tab